# How to convert nested foreach loop into LINQ query in C#

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

How to convert nested foreach loop into LINQ query in C# and i want to return list after querying the result.
List will return vale and description.
below code is working fine but i need to convert these 2 foreach loops into a single LINQ query.

```
        List<ListItem> listCodes = new List<ListItem>();
    
        foreach (var staticValueGroupMember in staticValueGroupMembers)
        {
            string description = string.Empty;
            if (staticValueGroupMember != null)
            {
                foreach (var staticValue in staticValues)
                {
                    if (staticValue.Value == staticValueGroupMember.MemberCode.ToString())
                    {
                        description = staticValue.Description;
                        break;
                    }

                }

                listCodes.Add(new ListItem() { Value = staticValueGroupMember.MemberCode.ToString(), Description = description });
            }
        }

        return listCodes;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty much a direct translation.

```
List<ListItem> listCodes =
(
    from staticValueGroupMember in staticValueGroupMembers
    where staticValueGroupMember != null
    join staticValue in staticValues
        on staticValueGroupMember.MemberCode.ToString() equals staticValue.Value
    select new ListItem()
    {
        Value = staticValueGroupMember.MemberCode.ToString(),
        Description = staticValue.Description
    }
).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi i am getting an error - the Method Join is not Supported , Exception -> NotSupportedException

Comment: As we have used Ioc Unity Container in our WPF MVVM , we cannot use Join for this particular it is throwing exception: Microsoft.Practices.unityResolutionFailedException

Comment: @AmanAgrawal - And you have explained that in the question? WHat are the types of `staticValueGroupMembers` & `staticValues`?

Comment: i am storing  both as a list.         Like Below                                                               var staticValueGroupMembers = (from staticValueGroupMember in MetadataEntityFactory.Entities.StaticValueGroupMember
                                           where staticValueGroupMember.SetCode == setCode
                                           && staticValueGroupMember.GroupCode == groupCode
                                           select staticValueGroupMember);

Comment: @AmanAgrawal - Then `Join` should work if they are just lists. LINQ is LINQ.

Comment: problem is we have used Ioc Unity Container in our WPF MVVM project. where we are getting Microsoft.Practices.unity.ResolutionFailedException when i use JOIN/ALL/ANY in my LINQ

Comment: @AmanAgrawal - "The exception thrown by the Unity container when an attempt to resolve a dependency fails." That's nothing to do with join. Your problem isn't with the LINQ query.

Comment: yes u are absolutely correct , but i do not know how to resolve this problem.

Comment: @AmanAgrawal - Then this answer answers your question and you probably need to now ask a new question.

Comment: But there are ways to get it through means  do not know how to use Expand in this situatuion inside LINQ to resolve this

Comment: @AmanAgrawal - Is it because of the call for `.MemberCode`?

Comment: @AmanAgrawal Like Enigmativity said this exception is not caused by Join, All, Any. Either a) Open a new question where you provide the exact error message and stack trace. Or b) Look into the stacktrace yourself/use the debugger and it will show you exactly which method and which codepath caused this exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
var result = staticValueGroupMembers
    .Where(gm => gm != null)
    .Join(staticValues,
        outer => outer.MemberCode.ToString(),
        inner => inner.Value,
        (outer, inner) => new ListItem()
        {
            Value = outer.MemberCode.ToString(),
            Description = inner.Description
        })
    .ToList();
```

Here is the detail of the [Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=netcore-3.1) method.

Comment: Can't use Join/LL/Any getting an Microsoft.practices.unity.ResolutionFailedException .